# How to access device(both mobile and pc) camera from a web app?

Tags: javascript, html

I want something like this, that works both in mobile and pc.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

It presently doesn't allow me to capture image in pc.

I know I can use getUserMedia(), but I don't want to stream video and also write a lot of js code.